# Trouble with line break in list items

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have problems while add line breaks into my listviews. Actually I have `white-space: normal; width: 80%;` but nothing happens. There is always "...". What line/ element in my code block these function?
[image]

```
    <div class="ui-page" data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="own posts" >

<div data-role="header" >
    <a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="edit" href="#create post" >search</a>
    <h1>loca</h1>    
  </div>



 <div class="ui-content">

<?php
include("new.php");
?>
<h2>own posts:</h2>
    <div name="first" data-demo-html="true">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

                <?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>


                    <li data-corners="false" style="margin-top:1%" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" >
                    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"></div><div class="ui-btn-text"><a class="ui-link-inherit"></a><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong></strong><?php
                    $curenttime = $row['time'];
  $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
  echo timeAgo($time_ago); ?></p>
                        <p style="white-space: normal; width: 80%;font-size: 102%;" class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong></p>
                        <p style="white-space: normal; width: 80%;font-size: 101%;" class="ui-li-desc"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>

                        <p style="font-size: 101%;" class="ui-li-desc">location: <?php echo $row['town']; ?></p> 
         <div class="ui-grid-a">
         <div style="width:80%" class="ui-block-a">
         <a class="commentbtn" data-rel="button" >comment</a>           
            <div id="createcomment" class="comment" >
    <form style="width:70%" data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post">
        <div class="content">
        <div id="showcomments" >
    <?php
include("showcom.php");
?>
    <?php foreach ($commen as $keyCommen => $rowCommen): ?>
    <div>
    <p style="display : inline;" class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $rowCommen['username']; ?>:</strong></p>
                        <p style="display : inline;" class="ui-li-desc"><?php echo $rowCommen['comment']; ?></p>

                        </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />
         <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></div>
         <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext">
        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-enhanced="true" value="Enhanced - Icon only">
    </div></div>        
        </div>      
    </form>
    </div>
        </div> 


         <div style="width:20%" class="ui-block-b">
             <div id="deletepost" class="delete" >
    <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./deleteposts.php" method="post">
        <div class="content">       
         <input type="hidden" name="idelete" id="idelete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="foot">

         <button type="submit" name="submit" data-role="none" data-icon="carat-r" class="button" >X</button>        
        </div>      
    </form>
    </div>      
    </div>
    </div>       
</div>
                    </li>                                   
        <?php endforeach; ?>        
</ul>
 </div>             

 </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not wrapping because you have no spaces in your text, just one really long word.

If you need to wrap one long word, use the CSS3  `word-wrap:break-word;`

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason. :)